# StringBuilder and accent

Tags: c#, encoding, stringbuilder

I have a `StringBuilder` and I want to write a text containing accent to an csv file.

**Code:**

```
StringBuilder strbr = new StringBuilder();
strbr.AppendLine("ù;é;à");
File.WriteAllText(filePath + ".csv", strbr.ToString());
```

But when I open my csv file, there is only: `Ã©`

The file "test.csv' correctly contain `ù;é;à`, but when I open it with Excel I have:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Maybe I missed a header for Excel?

Comment: The file is saved in UTF-8, as it should. Check the way you open the file. Does your editor support UTF-8?

Comment: The file will be saved with default encoding, say Win-1251. Put Encoding - utf-8 - explicitly: `File.WriteAllText(filePath + ".csv", strbr.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);`

Comment: Check the outputted CSV file with hex editor. Check if there is a UTF8 BOM mark at first bytes of the file. Then, check if the `ù;é;à` were encoded properly into a multi-byte sequence. From the screenshot it seems they were. It seems Excel did not notice that the CSV file was in UTF8. I'd guess the BOM were missing.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You right, thank you

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: why did you remove your answer?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: in order to test it when having quick downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file will be saved with *UTF-8* encoding, but read with *default one*, say Win-1251. You can *explicitly* specify an encoding (`UTF8` in this case):

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath + ".csv", strbr.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

**Edit**: I'm very sorry for my initial misleading explanation (thanks to [*Patrick Hofman*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993547/patrick-hofman) who has pointed it out). The actual problem is the *absence of BOM* ([Bite Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)): by default `File.WriteAllText` writes the text in the `UTF8` format *without* BOM:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,8a8ede9e1ec4fece

```
public static void WriteAllLines(String path, IEnumerable<String> contents)
{ 
    // ...
    InternalWriteAllLines(new StreamWriter(path, false, StreamWriter.UTF8NoBOM), contents);
}
```

then Excel reads the file, doesn't see any BOM and thus tries to read the file using the *default encoding*.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: Thank you! I'm sorry for my misleading explanation; reference source put it clear -  `InternalWriteAllLines(new StreamWriter(path, false, StreamWriter.UTF8NoBOM), contents);`

Answer (score 4):

Excel does not open a UTF8 CSV file properly if there's no BOM (0xEF,0xBB,0xBF) at the beginning of it. Many editors detect UTF8 in such case, but Excel seems to be bad at that, at least when importing CSV files.

I created a small CSV file:

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
00000000  C4 85 3B C4 99 3B C4 87 3B C5 BA 3B C5 84 0D 0A  Ä…;Ä™;Ä‡;Ĺş;Ĺ„..
```

and a second one:

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
00000000  EF BB BF C4 85 3B C4 99 3B C4 87 3B C5 BA 3B C5  ď»żÄ…;Ä™;Ä‡;Ĺş;Ĺ
00000010  84 0D 0A                                         „..
```

The files are identical except for the BOM marker.
Opening them in Excel gives, respectively:

[image]

[image]

Code from [**Dmitry Bychenko**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49942249/4298200) seems to emit BOM properly.

Comment: That's not side note but actually a real answer (since default encoding is utf without bom).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the encoding:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath + ".csv", strbr.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The default encoding is UTF-8! [Read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx): *This method uses UTF-8 encoding without a Byte-Order Mark (BOM)*. The "without BOM is the problem here.

Comment: It was actually the edit from Dmitry that made your answer wrong. Reverted that.